# How to link libcxx application to a C++ library compiled with gcc

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, libstdc++, libc++

I am trying to link an application that is compiled with clang/libc++ to the `v8-devel` system library on Fedora. However the latter is compiled with gcc/libstdc++ which leads to a linking error for `std::unique_ptr`, I think due to inlining.

Is there anything I can change in eiher my application code, or the compiler/linker flags (other than -stdlib) , such that my program can be linked to `v8-devel` while being still compiled with clang+libcxx?

Below a minimal toy example to reproduce the problem on Fedora (in reality, the only compiler that I have available is a custom clang version with libcxx, so switching to libstdc++ is not an option):

```cc
#include <libplatform/libplatform.h>
#include <v8.h>
using namespace v8;

int main(){
  std::unique_ptr<Platform> platform = platform::NewDefaultPlatform();
  V8::InitializePlatform(platform.get());
}
```

Then on Fedora we do:

```bash
# Install dependencies
yum install -y clang libcxx-devel v8-devel

# Try to compile test program
clang++ test.cpp -std=gnu++17 -stdlib=libc++ -lv8 -lv8_libplatform
```

Which gives the following linker error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/test-9925a1.o: in function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform(int, v8::platform::IdleTaskSupport, v8::platform::InProcessStackDumping, std::__1::unique_ptr<v8::TracingController, std::__1::default_delete<v8::TracingController> >)'
clang-14: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

You can automatically run the steps above using this [Dockerfile](https://gist.github.com/jeroen/4e73dbc10dbe4ad3ef3ada9d5c0b425a).

Comment: The different standard libraries are not binary-compatible. I do not see much of a chance of making this work. At the very least you need to make sure that the interface between your application and the library doesn't rely on anything from the standard library. Even then you would need to somehow modify all symbols in the application that rely on the standard library so that they are different between the two standard library implementations. Then you would need to do some linker trickery to link both of the standard libraries. And so on...

Comment: Even if there wasn't a linker error, the ABI between the application and library would be broken if it relies in any way on the standard library (e.g. because a class passed between the two has a `std::string` member). This can result in the program silently misbehaving or crashing.

Comment: I would just go and rebuild the library with your compiler/standard library. It is probably also not going to be straight-forward, but much easier and reliable.